# Password Validation / Requirements with Parse on the Cloud

Tags: validation, parse-platform, passwords

The typical process of creating a a new Parse user does not allow for server-side validation or any sort of input requirements.  These can be implemented on the client-side but can be easily circumvented by anyone willing to try.

So how would someone provide a Sign Up where the fields are checked against different requirements (defined by regex) in cloud code?

Two possibilities I see immediately:

1. An extra method that takes in all inputs as parameters, checks against regex, on success continues to Parse.User.signup() then returns session key and assigns it to the device that just signed up.
2. Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(...) before the user is saved you check the fields, and reject if it doesn't pass a test.

Problems I see with each:

1. EVERYONE with my AppID and a client ID can call this method.  Since the checks are being done server side there's need for additional filtering client-side which can be overwritten; an adversary could flood my Parse app with requests or bloated inputs.  Also you are then sending the user's password over the network.
2. The password is encrypted upon user creation(setting password), according to documentation I've read.  Everything but the password can be checked against a regex.